# Android, adb: How do I switch application to COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED state?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Since I don't understand if application in state `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED` starts as soon as I use it first time, I want to check it manually.

But I found no way to switch app to this state. With `adb` I can only do `enable`, `disable` and `disable-user`.

Is it possible? Is so, how do I do that?